# How to filter by multiple elements with a searchFilter in GrapQL / Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, graphql, graphql-js

I want to filter by multiple Input Elements looking like this:
[Input Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqCzG.png)

The fields seen in the image should be filtered at the same time. If one isn't used it should still filter. I can show you the code I'm currently working with.

```
  let searchFilter:SearchableJobFilterInput = {
    or: [
      {
        categoryID: {
          matchPhrasePrefix: form.category
        },
        title : {
          matchPhrasePrefix: form.title
        }
      }
    ],

    
  };


  this.API.SearchJobs(searchFilter).then((searchedJobs: SearchJobsQuery) => {
    if(searchedJobs != null)
    {
      this.jobs = searchedJobs.items;
      this.changeDetection.detectChanges();
      console.log(this.jobs);
    }
    else {
      console.log('No Data for Filtered Jobs!')
    }
  })
}
```

Am I using the wrong functions? Isn't searchable what I need? Or is there any other/better way to search?

Comment: if query tested in playground (you should do it before coding) [for different use cases] then you should know how arg/variable should look like ... constructing it by code is a piece of cake

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately i don't get how the query could look like because if one element does not have any text to filter, it still filters for nothing and this makes it fail...

Comment: play with API on playground, come back with knowledge and show examples

Comment: The filter should be disabled or ignored if the value is empty. But how? Is there any possibility to do this in Graphql?

Comment: simply don't pass it (variable object) - but again ... test it in playground